# How to upload .rar or videos to Wampserver with php

Tags: php, wampserver

I'm trying to upload files to Wampserver using php. I can upload like any kind of text file, excels, html, images and .zip, but when I try to upload .rar or .mp4, even though the POST method on the browser shows a 200 the server doesn't allow it, so the file isn't stored on the server.

What I have to do to allow wampserver to accept some file extensions that I want? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does it work with small rar files or large images?

Comment: what is the error? Have you added any validations on file type extensions? if yes then add mp4 or rar to it

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings in the PHP.ini file. You're looking for:

'post_max_size'
'upload_max_filesize'

Set those to what the values you require are.